# Python Colorama reset sequence adding spaces after unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, colorama

I have the following line that needs to be printed: `"progress: |⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜|"`. I have `colorama` colour sequences inside the string to format the unicode character '⬜', like so:

```py
print(f"progress: |{Fore.GREEN}⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜{Style.RESET_ALL}")
```

The output I get, instead of only coloring the characters inside the two `|` characters, adds one space *per* `⬜` character printed.

[image: spaces added]

I tested characters in the `ord` code range 11000-11040, and this only appears to be the case with the characters `⬛` and `⬜`, with the `ord` codes 11035 and 11036 respectively. What is the reason for this and how do I correct this?

*Note:* the same will occur if I use the ANSI sequences directly rather than the strings stored in `Fore.GREEN` and `Style.RESET_ALL`.

Comment: "if I use the colorama sequences directly rather than the strings stored" to be clear, you mean the ANSI control sequences?

Comment: Yes, I apologize, I was initially thinking this was something to do with `colorama`, so I miswrote. Thanks for bringing that to my attention

Comment: I mean, the final formatted string is what it is, regardless of how it was constructed.

Comment: Yes, I just felt it should be noted in case it was brought up

Comment: An nterestingness: `print(f"progress: |{Fore.GREEN}⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜⬛{Style.RESET_ALL}|⬛⬜⬜⬜⬜⬜|")` shows each _Large Square_ in the latter five *wider* (or each one is surrounded with a narrow whitespace). This behaviour appears in Windows Terminal unlike if Python runs from `cmd` using the same font `'Cascadia Mono'` (where is _all_ "normal" with no additional spacing). So I guess that the issue has something to do with _glyph rendering engine_ (sorry, I can't remember right name for the latter thing). BTW, I used a _mix_ of white and black squares to ensure that `cmd` font does not render `�` (glyph0)